# Cannot install anything in VitualBox/Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I want to test Linux distros in both Win7 and Mac using VirtualBox, and have done that for a while, it seemed a very smooth process, but all of a sudden I have this error in Windows 7, after making the basic setting of selecting the iso

[image]

... it should be 'Start' and the installation should be able to start... Instead, I get this:

[image]

and then this

[image].

Reinstalling VirtualBox does not help. (v.4.3.14)

I have tested with different Linux distros, and also with Window 7... the same problem.

...Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an issue being currently investigated/worked as it is affecting many users:
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=62615

They recommend to disable third party software that works with DLL injection (Antivirus?) and update to the latest version 4.3.15.

(Would have made a comment but don't have the points yet)
Hope this helps.

Comment: updating to 4.3.16 now and the problem was solved